# How can I create a horizontal scrolling in ReactJs

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So this page https://at-home.club has a very cool horizontal effect where the pages just slide in smoothly. How can I achieve the same result in ReactJS. I have been wrecking my brains these past few days but without prevail I decided to post a question. I just want the horizontal scrolling effect where the pages scroll in. You can just fill the pages with different colors to distinguish them from one another.

I want to build a portfolio for myself and want to implement such a feature
Thank you...

Answer (score -1):

this is normal.
you can use locomotive-scroll, it is smooth-scroll js library.where you easily create horizontal scroll + smooth scroll.

here this library:

https://locomotivemtl.github.io/locomotive-scroll/